# GEE create imagecollection of a specific tile

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I'm trying to create an image collection from sentinel 2 chich will display aimages between two dates from **a specific tile** (T48QTD)

I couldn't find how to choose one specific tile .

```
// Map the function over one year of data and take the median.
// Load Sentinel-2 TOA reflectance data.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2019-10-14', '2019-12-08')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .select('B2','B3','B4','B8','QA60')
                  .filterBounds(geometry)
                  .map(maskS2clouds);

var rgbVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 0.3,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the you need to use the `MGRS_TILE` property to filter your collection metadata on:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
                  .filterDate('2019-10-14', '2019-12-08')
                  .filterMetadata('MGRS_TILE', 'EQUALS','48QTD')
```

Confusing bit is your property is probably `48QTD` and not `T48QTD`?